# Import setAttributes() method in a separated module

Tags: block-editor

Is there a possibility to import the setAttributes() method in a separated module, I mean in what package we can find that method outside the props of edit and save functions

Example: 
This is a separated component that is gonna be used in the inspector of a specific block:

```
export default class Color extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(...arguments);
    }

    render() {
      <div>
        <RangeControl
                help="Color"
                value={color}
                onChange={value => setAttributes({color: value})}
                min={0}
                        max={20}
        />
     </div>
    }
```

There is a possibility to pass the setAttributes method using the spread opera
tor on the component

```
<Color {...this.props.setAttributes} />
```

but I want something like:

```
const { setAttributes } = wp.packageName;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example or explanation of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: example added :)